# Distinct values in for loop of Jinja template

Tags: flask, jinja2

I have below template which provides me the result,

```
<input list="code" code="order" name="code">
            <datalist id="code">
                {% for col in purchase %}
                <option value="{{col[0]}}">
                {% endfor %}
            </datalist>
```

The result is generated with duplicates,

Result

```
davd
davd
fdsr3243vc
fdsr3243vc
fdsr3243vc
frere
frere
frere
```

Expecting to get distinct values as result,

```
davd
fdsr3243vc
frere
```

Tried using unique option,
**{% for col in purchase|unique %}**

But the result is same, any suggestion would be helpful

Comment: I cannot reproduce. What is the object passed in your flask controller? Maybe run a `type(purchase)` in Python to further debug already?

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of your code, `purchase` appears to be not just a simple list or sequence as you are accessing an item at index 0 of each item in the `purchase` list. `unique` is probably working as intended its just probably that the sequence within the list `purchase` are all/most unique.

You could use "set comprehension" and pass it to the jinja2 template.

```py
@app.route("/purchase")
def purchase_list():
    purchase = # some database query
    purchase_unique = {col[0] for col in purchase}
    render_template("purchase_list.html", purchase=purchase_unique)
```

purhcase_list.html

```
<input list="code" code="order" name="code">
            <datalist id="code">
                {% for col in purchase %}
                <option value="{{ col }}">
                {% endfor %}
            </datalist>
```